# Strange server behavoir with huge spike in system load while number of context switches are small

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

We're seeing strange behavior on 3 of our machines. We're having trouble figuring what's going on under the hood. We're seeing:

1- A significant drop in the number of context switches.

2- A very large increase in the number of file-descriptors that the system is utilizing.

3- Our [system load](https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html) is too high, showing a sudden spike.

Is this workload familiar to anyone?

Our hypervisor is KVM, on a Xeon machine with 128 GB of RAM.

An image of the strange behavior:
[Open file descriptors vs Context witches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2lsY.jpg)